# How do I write in multiple positions in a Venn Diagram in PowerPoint?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, diagram

I want to make a similar chart to this , but using the smart Art feature in PowerPoint :

[image]

PowerPoint allows me to only write in one center line position of the Venn Diagram. while I need to make such a plot.

where actually it connects to a chart underneath

[image]

if you also check [the link to this chart](https://www.oliverwyman.com/our-expertise/insights/2018/dec/risk-journal-vol-8/rethinking-tactics/the-risk-of-machine-learning-bias-and-how-to-prevent-it.html)

It is animated, and also Icons are used.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying something too fine. As a graphic the Venn diagram can well be a bunch of separately drawn ellipses, separately inserted  text boxes and separate decorative shapes.

The SmartArt items have fixed structures - Generally one graphic item has one text. That cannot be changed.

The next image is an ordinary drawing. It has 2 ellipses, 3 text boxes and one decorative shape (=star):

[image]

It's not SmartArt. The idea that something which is named Text 3 is a subset of bigger compilation which contains also things named Text 1 and Text 2 is only an interpretation of the image, it's not relations between the shapes.

Mixing SmartArt items with separately drawn shapes spoils the whole idea, so if good Smart Art structures are not available, draw it as an ordinary drawing.

**Not asked:** In Powerpoint it's easy to make the items pop visible or land into the image as scheduled - that's another way how PowerPoint has succeeded to fool people to use their time by adding effects instead of making something useful.

Animation can be useful if it's not made by thinking only "it looks fine" but to show a real evolution such as how parts move or how the status of a thing is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Every software has limitations.

Powerpoint is not a drawing program, and the features for diagrams are limited.

I would use another software to draw the pieces of the diagram you need (for example one ellipse with text inside) and only assemble them inside powerpoint. This will keep your PowerPoint file more organized, of course with the limitation on the dependency on external software, but I prefer that rather than having individual text boxes.